# RedirectResponse in Symfony

Tags: php, http, symfony, redirect

I have a problem with the redirection to an external URL. 
I explain the problem: 
There is a form with a field for enter a payment card. When clicking to the button "payer". The system call the route "paiement".
I use the LemonWay api for payment. In the route payment, I register a new wallet for my customer, if no error I reditect to a second Route with name: "money_in_3d". In this route I call the MoneyIn3DInit from lemonway php api. 
If no error this method returned an ApiResponse object. This object contain an external url for verify 3d secure. But when I write:

```
return $this->redirect(urldecode($ret->acs->actionUrl));
```

This call not work. Nothing redirection. And when I see the network monitor of firefox, there is a line with: 
Status.     Method.      Url 
200.         OPTIONS.   the url

Why the method is OPTIONS ?  WH
hy the redirection not work ?

Comment: OPTIONS request sounds like a CORS preflight check. Are you perhaps using AJAX on the client side to load your various routes?

Comment: The method RegisterWallet and MoneyIn3DInit send request to the server of Lemonway and return an XML response. You think it is a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. 
When I 'm clicking on the button "Payer" they are a AJAX request but my server want do a redirection to a 3D secure URL, but it's not possible because a redirection don't return a JSON response so the redirection failed and firefox try a OPTION request.

Thank you !